# np-completeness in the bounded degree spanning tree

Tags: graph, tree, np-complete

I understand why the Bounded Degree Spanning Tree is considered NP Complete with a degree or 2 (it is an instance of the Hamiltonian Path Problem), but I do not understand why this applies to degrees > 2. If someone could please explain why this is an NP Complete problem for degree > 2, It would be most helpful

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Well, I think that you can make a simple reduction from the instance of bounded by 2, to the instance of General k.

Intuitivly, we will connect to each node of the original graph new k-2 nodes. Therefore every spanning tree will have to contain the k-2 edges from the original node to the new nodes that we connected to him, and a spanning tree from degree at most k exists if there is a spanning tree of degree at most 2 for the original graph.

The formal reduction will be:

F(V,E)=(V',E'), when : V'={(v,i)|v is in the original graph, 0 < i < k+1), E' = E U {((v,0),(v,i))}, and I don't write a formal proof for the correctness because after all we are not in a math forum.

Good luck and hope that it helped :)

Comment: Just a small correction. Instead of connecting each node of the graph to new k-2 nodes, connect nodes of the graph to total of new k-2 nodes.

Comment: @AnkitShubham Nope. I don't think that works. Nodes in a spanning tree of the graph you described may not have degree k unlike the one described in the answer above.